# Paths in WPF .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Trying to embed and use `font-awesome` fonts in a WPF application. The below works perfectly in .Net Framework when the font is in `/Assets/Fonts` folder:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">/AppName;Component/Assets/Fonts/FA5Regular400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Trying to do the same in a .Net Core 3.0 WPF app fails - the font does not show up. I read somewhere that the path handling has changed in .Net Core 3.0, but unable to pull up that article.

It seems to be a minor path issue - I really appreciate it if someone can help with this.

Comment: Have you tried to use a full URI? Or test if you can do it in code behind with a full URI? If you examine the assembly with ILSpy, is the font in the folder "Resources"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works provided that the *name* of the font is "Font Awesome" and that you have included the `.ttf` file as a resource in the Assets/Fonts folder of your project:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">pack://application:,,,/Assets/Fonts/#Font Awesome</FontFamily>
```

You should not include the name of the file in the pack URI.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, the build action must also be set to "Content" for the font file. Mine was set to "None". Thanks!